# print exe file's name assembly

Tags: api, assembly, nasm, argv

hello I am learning assembly language in windows 7, nasm, alink environment

I wonder how can I popup MessageBoxA with title its filename

what I tried is here

```
%include "win32n.inc"

extern MessageBoxA
import MessageBoxA user32.dll
extern ExitProcess
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll
segment .data USE32

message db "is opened",0

empty: 
times 128 db 0

segment .bss USE32

var1 resb 32

segment .code USE32

..start:

mov eax,empty
mov ebx, [ebp+4]
mov [eax],ebx

push dword MB_OK
push dword empty
push dword message
push dword 0
call [MessageBoxA]

push dword 0
call [ExitProcess]
```

I tried [ebp+4] to [ebp], [ebp+8], [ebp+12]

but have no luck.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path of the executabe by using [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Arguments are not put on stack by the Windows loader.